# Efficient way to output/display debugging data in a window

Tags: opengl, debugging, hud

I'm writing a program in Visual Studio, C++ with OpenGL and for the first time, I think it will be beneficial to see some live data on top of my display/render window.

To give some scope, I'm developing a 3D world with a ball bouncing and it would be nice to see things like the current velocity and y-positions of various objects, amongst other things.

What method is a nice/effective way to display this type of information to a window?
Is there any libraries, vs settings or third-party implementations that can be useful? (please excuse my naivety, I'm used to just `cout << some info`, on a console).

Comment: You're not using a specific engine, right?

Comment: What's wrong with spawning a console window and outputting to that?

Comment: @Byte56 I don't think there is anything wrong with that but I suspect that the OP doesn't want a log and wants more of a HUD where some info is displayed and refreshed every frame.

Comment: Just to clear things up, do you want the text in the same window as the graphics or in a separate window? Also to further clear things up, are you using a specific OS or is this code supposed to be portable.

Comment: @Byte56 I sometimes find it hard to follow data when there is a lot of things to output; it's sometimes hard to align data correctly in column, and when your data takes more than the usual 80 characters, well you get screwed a bit. Also, outputing to console may be more difficult when you have to output stuff coming from different places.

Comment: Well, you don't have to scroll the window. Just have it show info for the selected object and [replace the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271362/how-to-delete-printed-characters-from-command-line-in-c) instead of scrolling. Otherwise, more information on the technology you're using would be good (any libraries, etc.)

Comment: You may wish to use code similar to this to put the text on a bitmap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309767/c-windows-bitmap-draw-text
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132923/text-is-rotated-when-use-drawtext-on-bitmap

Comment: If all you want to log is textual, I'll second @Byte in strongly discouraging this. There are lots of existing console/file tools for searching, filtering, sorting, counting and otherwise processing text logs. This has been the subject of decades of development. Separate the concerns: Your game is for playing. Files and consoles are for logging.

Comment: You guys would discourage displaying debug stuff directly in the game window?

Comment: @Arthur, thanks for posting. To clarify, I was hoping to display a few details on the same window and only for the purposes of testing/developing (so just in vs on w7). Im also testing in full screen so cant really use another window. I'll check out links you posted. (:

Comment: Freetype-gl is a pretty nice, modern text rendering library for OpenGL. I use it mainly for in-game text, but it works for displaying some basic info too, whilst I'm profiling my game in full screen (getting a second monitor would work as well, if money grew on trees).  https://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/

Comment: I've read good things (it was easy to integrate and work with) about Anttweakbar (http://anttweakbar.sourceforge.net/doc/). I haven't used it myself though.

Answer (score 2):

Personally i have created a secondary GUI Layer and have a single class (c#) that handles all draw calls to this layer

information is passed in text format along with the sending object and the class organises the data before drawing it to screen

here is an exmple of the output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQo44.png

Answer (score 0):

AntTweakBar is nice for simple things, but C.

Comment: Some details would be appropriate. What is it? What does it do? Why is it good for this?